# Set the view before using comet3

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have this function in Matlab:

```
function uprime=G(t,u,a,b,r)
uprime=zeros(3,1);
uprime(1)=-a*u(1)+a*u(2);
uprime(2)=r*u(1)-u(2)-u(1)*u(3);
uprime(3)=-b*u(3)+u(1)*u(2);
```

Then this script:

```
close all
tspan=[0,100];
[t,u]=ode45(@G,tspan,init,[],a,b,r);
comet3(u(:,1),u(:,2),u(:,3))
```

What I'd like to do is set the view to

```
view(-4,8)
```

before the `comet3` plot begins. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to lock the axes:

```
...
view(-4,8);
hold on
comet3(u(:,1),u(:,2),u(:,3));
hold off
```

If you want to be more specific, you can just hold the current axis ([`gca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html)) or a handle to particular axis that you plotting to:

```
...
view(-4,8);
hold(gca,'on');
comet3(gca,u(:,1),u(:,2),u(:,3));
hold(gca,'off');
```

Comment: Can't get your suggestion to work. Can you adjust the code above so that it is complete and can you test it to make sure it works before posting it? Thank you.

Comment: I did test it. It holds the view of the axes and prevents `comet3` from adjusting them. The `...` part is everything before your call to `comet3` in the code in your question. I didn't test your `ode45` function because the question is not about that. Please be more descriptive rather than saying something doesn't work.

Comment: I added my code and resulting image to your answer. Only thing I could figure to do.

Comment: It looks my answer is working correctly. Your problem is probably either with your integration or you simply need to specify a different `view` or `axis`. Run `comet3` without the `hold on` an look at the `axis` limits that are chosen automatically.

Comment: Also, for future reference, you shouldn't edit answers to add your own code. Only edit to make corrections and clarifications. I'm going to roll back your edit.